# Dataframe manipulation, something with groupby, probably :/

Tags: python, pandas

Need help with a Dataframe transformation. I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C' : [1, 2,  1, 1, 2, 2,  1],
                   'D' : [1, 2, 13, 4, 5, 9, 10]})
df = df.sort('C')
=>       C   D
     0   1   1
     1   1  13
     2   1   4
     3   1  10
     4   2   2
     5   2   5
     6   2   9
```

And would like to get

```
    F1   F2   F3   F4
1    1   13   4    10
2    2    5   9   Nan
```

Currently, I loop over everything, but on large dataframe, it's just too slow.

Thanks

Comment: Actually I can't figured out how to pass from the dataframe to the other. May you clarify your question? What are F1,..,F4?

Comment: even i was wondering about that!.. they dont link with C and D,,, can you please recheck the data?

Comment: Agree, not clear, sorry.. Tried to make it clear, with a sort('C') in the question. The 2 rows of the new Dataframe I try to get come from the values of C. Does it help?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by adding a new F column and then calling `pivot`:

```
>>> df["F"] = "F" + (df.groupby("C").cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
>>> d2 = df.pivot(index="C", columns="F", values="D")
>>> d2
F  F1  F2  F3  F4
C                
1   1  13   4  10
2   2   5   9 NaN
```

The F and C there are the index and column names; if you really want to get rid of those you could set them to None.

```
>>> d2.index.name = None
>>> d2.columns.name = None
>>> d2
   F1  F2  F3  F4
1   1  13   4  10
2   2   5   9 NaN
```